# Encrypt or UUID for assigning external-facing IDs (Ruby API)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, api

We need to add a unique identifier to a handful of our models for external consumption. A couple of our tables have 10s of millions of rows. We're debating between encrypting our incrementing internal DB id (integer) OR using UUID (we use postgres, so it's built in) and backfilling our database. Here are the pros and cons as we see it:

**Encrypting our internal db id:**

*Pros*

- Using an OpenSSL cypher, it would be very little work to write a
  helper method to include on models we want to add a unique ID for
  external consumption.
- We wouldn't have to add any additional data to the database.
- We can convert to/from the DB id without actually loading the entire 
  object into memory.

*Cons*

- If our encryption key was ever lost/stolen, we would be stuck with that key anyways because the encrypted keys were already exposed externally.
- We have to add a prefix to the encrypted keys for each table/model because when two tables have the same ID, their encrypted ID will be identical (`message.first.encrypted_key` == `company.first.encrypted_key`).

**Using Postgres built-in UUID**

*Pros*

- There's no key to lose, so the UUID feels more permanent than encrypting.
- We guarantee uniqueness across tables, and even across databases when we shard.
- No need for prefixing, although it's kind of nice to prefix the external_id for readability. (like stripe does cus_123456)

*Cons*

- We will have to add a lot of data to the db.
- We will have to backfill the UUID on 10s of millions of rows.
- We won't be able to infer to the ID from the UUID, which means our queries will have to query with the UUID, which I assume is slower than decrypting and querying by an integer ID.

Am I missing any other glaring considerations?

We're leaning more towards encrypting because of the ease of implementation but this is a big, permanent decision.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd use a UUID. Querying by an indexed UUID shouldn't be slow, and crypto functions take measurable time.

Comment: +1 for the comment by @DaveNewton Also, UUID is a built in function for DBs and in the long run is going to be a lot easier to manage IMO

Comment: One question to consider, does this need to by cryptographically secured?  What are the consequences if someone figures out how correlate a given UUID with a particular record id?  What vulnerabilities would that pose for you?  In most cases, it is not catastrophic if someone discovers the id of a record, but I do not know your business logic and your use case.  Just food for thought.  If you require cryptographic security, ensure whichever method you chose provides that.  I do not know if Postgres UUID is crypto secure.